# Using Different Proxy Servers For Different Networks on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, proxy, ethernet

I'm using windows 10. I have two network card:

- Ethernet (172.16.1.0/24)
- WIFI (192.168.1.0/24)

To connect via Ethernet I must use a proxy 172.16.1.100.

I have to go and change the proxy settings (in Internet Options) to be able to use the intranet network (Ethernet card). When I need to connect to internet via WIFI, I have to then go and turn them off. It's a small thing, but considering this is something I have to do every time, it's a bit annoying.

Is there any way I can make Windows automatically configure proxy settings  based on the network I'm connected to?